# Реализация поддержки Flash в андроид браузере

Tags: android, flash, chromium, flash-player

Необходимо реализовать поддержку flash в браузере на андроид. Flash должен поддерживаться именно самим приложением, без внешней установки плагина. Куда копать? Может есть какие-то готовые решения или что-то подобное. Браузер на chromium.

Answer (score 0):

попробуй **shumway**, это виртуальная машина на js с поддержкой as2, as3
shumway работает c swg и рендерит его в html5 (video, sound тоже поддерживаются). имеются гибкие возможности по настройки рендера и т.п

https://github.com/mozilla/shumway

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/308877)

Comment: Добавте основное из ссылка прямо в тело вопроса. "Голые" ссылки в ответе обычно удаляются.

Comment: ребята, так нормально?

Comment: @Эникейщик так ок?